# Very strange: Why the order of my objects get messed up after a ajax call even I have not changed anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have **two nested** ajax calls to server.

In 1st ajax call, server returns me the XML which contain ordered list of objects, server order the list by date ascending order. Here, I do get objects in date's ascending order.

In the second ajax call's success function, I simply output the dates of objects, but my objects are suddenly surprisingly **not in date's ascending order**, why?

My code looks like below (please don't feel confused about my two ajax calls, I explained them after the code):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : MY_URL_1,
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("DOCUMENT").each(function() {
               var eachXMLdata = $(this);
               var date = eachXMLdata.children("DATE").text();

               // I successfully get the date in ascending order
               console.log('date:'+date);



               $.ajax({
               type : "GET",
               url : MY_URL_2,
               dataType : "xml",
               success : function(xml) {
                        
                         var date = eachXMLdata.children("DATE").text();
             
                         //I have not change anything of eachXMLdata, 
                         //why the order of the dates get messed up here
                         console.log('date:'+date);


                    }//end of 2nd ajax success function
                });// end of 2nd ajax call

            });//end of "each" function
        }//end of 1st ajax success function
     });//end of 1st ajax call
```

As you saw above, there are two nested ajax calls, that's the second ajax call is inside first ajax call's success function (and in the "each" function).

In the **first** ajax call, I console output the date of each object, which is **correctly showing in ascending order**.

The strange problem comes after I output the objects' date again in the **second** ajax call's success function, the dates are no longer in ascending order, why? **I have not change anything of `eachXMLdata`, why two console outputs give me different order of the dates?**  and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Isn't this expected ? The 2nd wave of Ajax calls are emitted in sequence, but the responses have absolutely no guarantee to arrive in the same order.

Comment: @Tibo, if you read my code carefully, the console output data in the 2nd ajax is still the data returned from 1st ajax, the 2nd ajax does not change anything, but for some reason changed the order

Comment: @leem it probably did change something, it probably added the second "wave" of data to your first so you have two sets of data ordered properly but, now you have not merged them first then order it if that makes sense.

Comment: @Leem: I don't get your point. Even if the data in the 2nd handler is the same as it's "parent" handler, the *order* in which those are executed is undefined - unless the server processes requests in a pure serial fashion, which is something you can't rely on. Try using a 'beforeSend' callback - that will be called in the expected order.

Comment: @Tibo, the server ordered the objects by date then send to client. and what do you mean about "beforeSend" callback?

Comment: @Leem: 'beforeSend' is a callback you can use in your $.ajax call. It is triggered before the request leaves the client. 'success' is called when the server's answer arrives at the client. Anyway, as Paul Grime pointed out, I find your code pretty convoluted. What is it you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Tibo, my outer ajax call get a list of objects, then I loop through each object, check if the "name" attribute of each object is empty or not, if it is empty, I call the inner ajax to query the "name" from somewhere else, then after I make sure each object has a name value, I pupulate each object in a row of html table. That's why I need to use the object returned from the outer ajax in the inner ajax success function to populate all attributes in a row of the table. Hope you understand what I am actually doing now.

Comment: Hi, I finally get rid of the problem by set "async: false" for the inner ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get rid of the problem by set "`async: false`" for the inner ajax call. This is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bv2YY/) demo works fine. Is it your use of the `text()` function?

```
var xmlstr = "<DOCUMENT>";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    xmlstr += "<DATE>" + i + "</DATE>";
}
xmlstr += "</DOCUMENT>";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/xml/",
    data: {
        "xml": xmlstr
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("DOCUMENT").each(function() {
            var eachXMLdata = $(this);

            eachXMLdata.children("DATE").each(function() {
                // I successfully get the date in ascending order
                $(document.body).append($("<div/>").text('1date:' + this.firstChild.nodeValue));
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/echo/xml/",
                data: {
                    "xml": xmlstr
                },
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {

                    eachXMLdata.children("DATE").each(function() {
                        //I have not change anything of eachXMLdata,
                        //why the order of the dates get messed up here
                        $(document.body).append($("<div/>").text('2date:' + this.firstChild.nodeValue));
                    });

                } //end of 2nd ajax success function
            }); // end of 2nd ajax call
        }); //end of "each" function
    } //end of 1st ajax success function
}); //end of 1st ajax call
```

Comment: interesting, why I got different orders ... :(

Comment: Why do you need to do the same `eachXMLdata.children("DATE").text()` in the inner function anyway? Just use the `date` variable from the outer function.

Comment: @ Paul, my outer ajax call get a list of objects, then I loop through each object, check if the "name" attribute of each object is empty or not, if it is empty, I call the inner ajax to query the "name" from somewhere else, then after I make sure each object has a name value, I pupulate each object in a row of html table. That's why I need to use the object returned from the outer ajax in the inner ajax success function to populate all attributes in a row of the table.